# How to Solve the Matrix Equation $WB = AV$?

Tags: linear-algebra

We have the matrix equation $WB=AV$ where $B,A$ are given and $W,V$ are to be solved. Obviously the solution is not unique. Is there a possible way of computing it?

Comment: It seems like there's a lot of non-uniqueness: If one of $A$ or $B$ is invertible (say $A$), then $A^{-1}WB = V$, and for any $W$, there's a $V$ so that $WB = AV$. If neither is invertible, I don't think the situation is much improved. Or am I completely misunderstanding the question?

Comment: An obvious solution is to take $W$ and $V$ zero matrices of appropriate sizes. Do you want to find _all_ solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how to compute this efficiently, but I know that a result for the general form of the solution. A solution only exists if the range of $WB$ is contained in the range of $A$, so the first step is to pick *any* $W$ such that the range of $WB$ is contained in the range of $A$. Clearly this is possible with basically no computation, but perhaps there are some choices that would be numerically wise - I can't help you there. Then it is known that $V$ will exist and the general solution for $V$ will be of the form
$$ V = A^{\dagger}WB + (I - A^{\dagger}A)Y$$
where $A^{\dagger}$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of $A$, and $Y$ is any matrix where the number of rows of $Y$ is equal to the number of columns of $A$, and the number of columns of $Y$ is equal to the number of columns of $B$. So you can basically just pick any $Y$.

Comment: How can this be derived? What if I want both V and W to be invertible?

Comment: @Strin, to derive this theorem, you should decompose all the matrices into their singular value decompositions.

Answer (score 1):

For any $C$,  let $W=AC$, $V=CB$ then $WB=ACB=AV$